# How to understand the following regex expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex expression in Perl that I've been trying to figure out for a while, but still have trouble understanding what it does. The regex is the following:

```
($last,$first,$middle) = $name =~ /^(.*)_([A-Z][^A-Z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)?/;
```

The `(.*)` means any sequence of characters, `_` followed by underscore, not sure what `([A-Z][^A-Z]*)` and `([A-Z][a-z]*)?` do.

And also how is expression executed? Is this same as below:

```
$name =~ /^(.*)_([A-Z][^A-Z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)?/;
($last,$first,$middle) = $name
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: characters inside the 1st capturing group goes to the variable `last`, second goes to `first` and the optional third goes to `middle`

Comment: As for the second part: No. Think of the `=~` operation as returning a list. It would be more like `$name =~ /^(.*)_([A-Z][^A-Z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)?/; $last = $1; $first = $2; $middle = $3;`. Also, parsing peoples' names like that might be [a bad idea](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: There are various tools online that can help you understand/visualise regex patterns, for example: https://www.debuggex.com/r/NinulRIdvbrpu04w

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I really like the debuggex!